# How to displaying twits or dynamic data from social media....?

Tags: java, jsp

can i knom how twits are displaying in the section "Sample Sentence from Social Media on 'Misty' " in the site dictionary30.com/meaning/Misty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're pulling tweets to do with the context from Twitter. Have a look at [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

With Twitter4J you could pull the tweets with whatever context you want in real time. e.g location based, hashtag based, name based etc! If you wanted to then build something like what is on that website you could use JQuery to render them. Make a shiney slinder! :)